# awk vs perl in reading a csv?

Tags: perl, awk

I am in need of speed here. I have a csv file of 500mb size ( actually there are many csv but i am considering only one right now )
I need to read the 3rd column and pick the unique strings from it. The following methods i have tested and i find only awk is the fastest

**Using perl:**

- read the file using the traditional way open the file and pass the
  file handle to the while loop
- unset the $/ variable and slurp the entire file into string and then
  split the lines and pick 3rd field and proceed
- use File::Slurp module
- use Text::CSV / XS to read the csv and do the needful

**In all the above ways it takes around 500 seconds to parse the csv.**

**But if i try to do the same using awk it completes in almost 10 seconds.**

I am still learning my steps in perl , and recently my passion towards it was growing a lot after seeing its power of hash. But this problem has taken me
back. Is this some limitation of perl where unix tools have the upper hand ?

I know Text::CSV is the best way to handle a csv file. But speed is my concern and i can gurantee that my csv does not have any embedded comma or other problem which only Text::CSV takes care of.

**UPDATE : Found my problem**

```
my %hash;
my $file = $ARGV[0] or die "Need input CSV $!\n";
open(my $fh,'<',$file) or die "Could not open the $file $!\n";
while(my $line = <$fh>)
{
chomp($line);
my $field2=(split /|/, $line)[2];  #I missed to quote the pipe delimiter
$hash{$field2}++;
}
print "$_\n" for keys %hash;
```

**ANOTHER UPDATE : issue and fix**

My csv was delimited by '|' and i missed out quote them. Because of which the execution time was slowed down significantly and also the output that it yielded was wrong which i failed to notice . After quoting the delimiter the script was able to complete in around 18 seconds and when i used @Borodin logic of limiting the field splitting then the execution time further reduced. i am able achieve same speed as awk.

I still find Text::CSV approach slower , anyway since my file can work with the default split approach , i am going to go with it.

Comment: Show us the code, and a few sample input lines.

Comment: Slurping a 500 MiB file is not a good idea.  How wide is each row (how many rows in your 500 MiB file)?  How many fields?  How are you collecting the 3rd column? What are you doing with it once you've collected it?  Did you try Perl in 'awk` mode (`perl -n -a -F, -l -e 'print $F[2]'`)?

Comment: [Text::CSV_XS](http://search.cpan.org/~hmbrand/Text-CSV_XS-1.05/CSV_XS.pm) is pure C; it might speed your code up a tad.

Comment: how does `cut -d '|' -f 3 | sort -u` do, if that's all you need?

Comment: yeah , cut/awk + sort was good from the start. I was just wondering why perl was slow. Now i am happy that i found the problem and solution

Comment: @ysth: yeah, I noticed that what had been CSV was now PSV.

Comment: sorry , I should have put all these details when i posted my question here. My bad.

Comment: well if you are not worried about sorting and just want the unique values , no need to use `uniq` or `sort -u` , awk has associative array ( a.k.a hash in perl :D ) `awk -F"," '{a[$3]++}END{for(i in a){print i}}' filename`

Comment: aah.. just now saw you have already used it.

Comment: My timing on `cut -d, -f 3 junk.data | sort -u` (same size file as in my answer, but different random seed, so a different file) finds that the `cut` takes around 15 seconds, but the sort takes forever (I got bored at 1m20s, 2m16s, and 3m59s on various attempts). That's puzzling — an unexpectedly long time. (`sort` alone ran to completion in about 3m45s; that's without the overhead of a pipe; add 15s for `cut` writing to file and maybe I was just a second or two too impatient. Running `time sh -c 'cut -d, -f3 junk.data | sort -u >junk.out` took about 3m57s. Weird it didn't finish before.

Comment: There is no need for the `chomp`, and `++$hash{$field2}` is likely to be fractionally faster than `$hash{$field2}++`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would help to see the problem if you had shown your Perl code. There is no need for the overhead of `Text::CSV` for the file you describe, where the data never contains commas (and presumably no quotes?)

Your program should look something like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

open my $fh, '<', 'myfile';

my %data;

while (<$fh>) {
  my $col3 = (split /,/, $_, 4)[2];
  ++$data{$col3};
}

print "$_\n" for keys %data;
```

Comment: Thanks , this really helped me. I have updated in my question the mistake i did that slowed the program

Answer (score 6):

I generated a 350 MiB file with 10,000,000 rows similar to:

```
part1,part2,data856801,part4,part5
```

(where the number in the third column was a random value between 100,000 and 999,999) and used a home-built Perl 5.18.1:

```
time perl -n -a -F, -l -e '$a{$F[2]}++;
           END { foreach $key (sort keys %a) {print "$key";} }' junk.data >junk.perl.output
```

This took about 34 seconds. Without the `sort`, it took about 33 seconds (I got some variance on the times).  The time with the system-provided Perl 5.16.2 was essentially the same.

For comparison, using BSD `awk` (20070501):

```
time awk -F, '{a[$3]++} END {for (key in a) print key}' junk.data > junk.awk.output
```

This took about 29 seconds, yielding the data in an unsorted order.  GNU `awk` 3.1.7 took about 15 seconds (impressively faster).

Simply using `cat` or `cp` on the file took just over 5 seconds.

All the filtered output files had 899993 lines in them; the consistency is good.

Thus, it seems for this job, Perl is slightly slower than `awk`, but not by a factor of 50 on my machine.  I'm not sure how much optimization can be done on the Perl script; what I've written is very simple and crude.

Testing on:

- MacBook Pro (early 2011), 2.3 GHz Intel Core i7.
- 16 GiB 1333 MHz DDR3 RAM.
- 750 GiB 5400 rpm disk.
- Mavericks 10.9.2
- Perl 5.18.1 (5.16.2)
- BSD `awk` 20070501
- GNU `awk` 3.1.7

I had iTunes playing music in the background, and was typing in the browser, so the system was not idle while the tests were run.

---

Using Text::CSV with Text::CSV_XS and the following script, it took almost 49 seconds:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::CSV;

my %a;
my $csv = Text::CSV->new ( { binary => 1 } )  # should set binary attribute.
                   or die "Cannot use CSV: ".Text::CSV->error_diag ();

open my $fh, "<:encoding(utf8)", "junk.data" or die "junk.data: $!";
while ( my $row = $csv->getline( $fh ) )
{
    $a{$row->[2]}++;
}
$csv->eof or $csv->error_diag();
close $fh;

print "$_\n" for keys %a;
```

---

#### Perl running fast

Interestingly, [Borodin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/622310/borodin)'s [script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22740351/15168) took about 17 seconds, quite a bit faster than the Perl-as-`awk` mode operation.  It would be interesting to know if Perl manages to optimize the split since it knows it only needs the third field, whereas the `awk` mode has to split five fields in each line (for the sample file), even though only the third is used.

This is very comparable with the GNU `awk` time.

Comment: Borodin's script explicitly says only split up to 4 fields - perl isn't automatically doing that optimization (though it does optimize `(undef,undef,$col3)=split...`)

Comment: for an extra burst of speed, you can try building a perl with Configure -Dusefaststdio (though enough stuff now relies on the PerlIO layer that that's not good for general use anymore)

Comment: `split(/|/,$text)` , i understand perl treats pipe as regex without quoting it , but why does it slow it down

Comment: Because it is looking for empty or empty as the separator, then creating one column of output for each character in each line.  Dramatically slower!  And note that it is really important to show what you're trying because we might well have spotted the trouble quickly.

Comment: hey Johnathan , just being curious , how did you generate a junk csv of specified limit and data. Just use print statement and rand function in a while loop until the file reaches specified size ?

Comment: I have/wrote a C program called, with great originality, `random`: `Usage: random [-fhisV] [-F format] [-S seed] [-n count] [[low] high]
  -f         Print floating point numbers
  -h         Print this help message and exit
  -i         Print integer numbers
  -n count   Print this many random numbers
  -s         Report seed
  -F format  Print numbers using given format
  -S seed    Seed the random number generator with given seed
  -V         Print version information and exit`.  I used the command line: `random -n 10000000 -F 'part1,part2,data%6d,part4,part5' 100000 999999 > junk.data`.